# Xpages - Adding anchor tag to a column in Notes view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, notesview

I want to add a link into a column in Notesview, I saw an example at [searchdomino](https://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Write-HTML-and-JavaScript-in-Notes-view-rows-and-columns-on-the-Web) when I tried it failed with the error "An operator or semicolon was expected but none was encountered", all other effort prove abortive.

Below is the example from searchdomino:

```
<a href='#' 
onClick="window.open('/"+@WebDbName+"/Employee/"+@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)+"?deleteDocument ','_new');window.location.reload()">Delete</a>
```

With the error:

```
An operator or semicolon was expected but none was encountered
```

[image]

I was able to surpress the error doing the below, but could not call the onclick event.

```
"<a href='#' onClick='window.open'>" + "/"+@WebDbName+"/employee.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId="+@Text(@DocumentUniqueID) + "</a>"
```

Your input will be appreciated.

Injecting notesview column values into html table, sample code:

```
 if(entryData[j].getAttribute("columnnumber") == "1") {            
    var xpageName = "page.xsp";
    var sURL = strURL[0] + ".nsf/" + xpageName + "?documentId=" + viewEntry[i].getAttribute("unid") + "&action=editDocument";

    result += "<tr> ";

    if(entryData[j].childNodes[1].childNodes.length == 0) {
        result += "<td><a href='" + sURL + "'>(NO_VALUE)</a></td>"
    } else {
        result += "<td><a href='" + sURL + "'>" + entryData[j].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</a></td>"
    }
} else {
    if(entryData[j].childNodes[1].childNodes.length == 0) {
        result += "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
    } else {
        result += "<td>" + entryData[j].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td>"

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the source of this part of your Xpage?

Comment: I added sample code above which injects column values into an html table.

Answer (score 3):

You've got three levels of quoting to deal with there, so I think this is what you need:

```
{<a href='#' onClick="window.open('/}  + @WebDbName +  {/Employee/} +@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)+ {?deleteDocument ','_new');window.location.reload()">Delete</a>}
```

I.e, this is using...

- { } for quoting the formula string value
- " " for quoting the onClick attribute value within the formula string value
- ' ' for the quoting the window.open argument values within the onClick attribute value within the formula string value.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTML code you are generating, you will see that you don't pass any arguments to window.open.
Your code:

```
"<a href='#' onClick='window.open'>" + "/"+@WebDbName+"/employee.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId="+@Text(@DocumentUniqueID) + "</a>"
```

This would render something like this:

```
<a href='#' onClick='window.open'>/database.nsf/employee.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=26176F6E8AC2362E3</a>
```

You need to move the URL inside your onClick event, like this:

```
<a href='#' onClick='window.open("/database.nsf/employee.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=26176F6E8AC2362E3")'>Click this link</a>
```

Or why not just this:
    Click this link